# why my Null substitution is not working in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have written a programme in c# and used automapper to map.I have used Null substitution but it is not substituting the given value in result i am getting null only.please check the below code.I want my result to show 8099000078.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Automapper;

namespace Automapper
{
    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
    }
    public class Patient
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User obj = new User();
            obj.FirstName = "sujit";
            obj.LastName = "kumar";
            obj.Address = "Bangalore";
            obj.Mobile = "";

            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, Patient>().ForMember(
                emp => emp.Name, map => map.MapFrom(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.Address))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.phone, source => source.NullSubstitute("8099000078"));

            var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User, Patient>(obj);

           // Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
           // Console.WriteLine(result.Location);
            Console.WriteLine(result.phone);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters I would not use the namespace `Automapper`.  It would be VERY easy to have a typo that would prevent you from using the right namespace (like you do in your `using` block).

Answer (score 3):

You missed how null substitute works.

From [AutoMapper Wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Null-substitution):

> Null substitution allows you to supply an alternate value for a
>   destination member if the source value is null anywhere along the
>   member chain.

In your code you didn't provide any source for `phone` property, therefore it doesn't have any value to check on null and it does not perform null substitution.

I made some changes in your code to make it works (see below):

```
void Main()
{
    User obj = new User();
    obj.FirstName = "sujit";
    obj.LastName = "kumar";
    obj.Address = "Bangalore";
    obj.Mobile = null;

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<User, Patient>()
        .ForMember(emp => emp.Name, map => map.MapFrom(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Location, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.Address))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.phone, source => source.MapFrom(x => x.Mobile))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.phone, source => source.NullSubstitute("8099000078")));

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var result = mapper.Map<User, Patient>(obj);

    result.Dump();
}

public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
}
public class Patient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

Here I provided a source for `phone` property (I mapped it from `Mobile`) and set the `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.phone, source => source.MapFrom(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Mobile) ? a.Mobile : "8099000078"));
```

Comment: Hi Amit it is working fine but i want it should work with NullSubstitute,can you provide any solution for this.

Comment: I'll look into it for sure

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Automapper before, but looking at your syntax it appears that 'source' would never be null because you pass it a valid obj (thus never having the NullSubstitute() return 8099000078.

I don't see where you're trying to map dest => dest.phone, source => source.Mobile.